# how to make a outlined input with floating label with custom css?

Tags: css

I want to make an input with the floating label. Exactly like the material-ui for react.

Material UI Code :

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-basic"
  label="E-Mail"
  variant="outlined"
  placeholder="Enter E-Mail"
  />
```

Link for seeing output for the above code : [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-turing-gfcnn?file=/src/App.js:100-232)

What I want is, the label must be inside the input field. When the user is clicking the input field, the label should float and the placeholder should be shown. If the user doesn't enter anything and if the focus changes, again the placeholder must be hidden and the label must comeback to initial position

What I have tried so far is :

```css
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .material-textfield {
    position: relative;
    }

    label {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1rem;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: white;
    color: gray;
    padding: 0 0.3rem;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    transition: 0.1s ease-out;
    transform-origin: left top;
    pointer-events: none;
    }
    input {
    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1rem 0.7rem;
    color: gray;
    transition: 0.1s ease-out;
    }
    input:focus {
    border-color: #6200ee;
    }
    input:focus + label {
    color: #6200ee;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%) scale(0.9) !important;
    }
    input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9) !important;
    }

    input:empty + label {
    transform: translateY(75%);
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    input:empty:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9) !important;
    }

    input:empty::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="material-textfield">
      <input placeholder="placeholder" type="text" />
      <label> label</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to create a runnable HTML/CSS snippet here on Stack Overflow instead of making people go to other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were mostly there with your code. The most important thing to note, `:empty` means nothing for inputs. It will always be applied because inputs can't have children.

Though the `:placeholder-shown` is pretty much the main workaround to styling an empty input.

I removed most of the `:empty` styles and replaced some with `:placeholder-shown`.

The other thing I did was I set up the focus and not-empty transitions to be the same.

```
input:not(:focus)::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This makes it so the placeholder is hidden only when it's not focused.

Here's the full results:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.material-textfield {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  transform-origin: left top;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem 0.7rem;
  color: gray;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: #6200ee;
}

input:focus+label {
  color: #6200ee;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9) !important;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9) !important;
}

input:not(:focus)::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="material-textfield">
    <input placeholder="placeholder" type="text" />
    <label> label</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

That all being said, there are some accessibility issues with the Material Design shrink labels. So, just make sure you are aware of potential issues.

https://www.matsuko.ca/blog/stop-using-material-design-text-fields/

Comment: Thank You So Much @Zachary

Comment: but if we are not giving placeholder, the label is on floating state. How can i fix it?

Comment: Add a default placeholder of `' '` (an empty space). The placeholder will still "exist" but won't be visible due to being whitespace.

Comment: is there no other work around for this? :(

Comment: Not really. You can also fully control the value in the input (i.e. React controlled components) such that you know for certain in the JS that it has a value or not. The placeholder-shown trick is pretty much the only good way to do this. If you are setting it up as a component in a framework of any kind, it's easy enough to add a default value of `' '`